# Can't boot up Ubuntu after changing grub file with nomodeset?

Tags: grub2, screen, nomodeset

So I was trying to get Ubuntu to be able to change the screen brightness correctly, and in one of the forum posts, someone suggested to try to change the grub file with "nomodeset." After I did so, my Ubuntu boots up to a full purple screen and gets stuck there.

I pretty much need to be able to modify my grub file again and change it to what it originally was. How can I do that?

Help please?

**EDIT:**

I tried booting into recovery mode, but I can't get past the black screen with all the text written on it. I think I'm getting a udevd error related to my graphics card.

Comment: did you take the backup of grub file that you changed? or do you remember what changes you applied?

Comment: Yea I changed the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash nomodeset"` on accident

Comment: Check my answer. and one more thing to fix the `brightness` you have to replace the line with : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` not what you've mentioned.. ;)

Comment: Have you tried the way [MadMide](http://askubuntu.com/users/75166/madmike) suggested? It is going to be so difficult if you even not be able to login using `safe mode`. It was the last option from my opinion. Hope his method works for you.. Give it a try.. Reply..

Comment: Enjoy and keep playing with Ubuntu.. Don't forget to say thanks to [MadMike](http://askubuntu.com/users/75166/madmike) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to change boot options temporarily

- Boot your system.
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to show the Grub-Menu if Ubuntu is your only system.
- Go to the menu entry you want to (temporarily) change and hit <kbd>e</kbd>.
- Delete the "nomodeset" from the kernel options.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to continue booting.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps**

- Open your system in `Recovery Mode`, *2nd* option from the `Grub Menu`, when your system starts. You may have to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting if your system starts without `Grub Menu`.
- When starts select **grub** from the listed menu. It will ask like: `your system will open in read/write mode`. Chose `yes`. After updating your grub it will exit and again will come to the listed options.
- Again chose **root** from the list.
- now run following command to open your `/etc/default/grub` file:

  ```
  nano /etc/default/grub
  ```

  go to the line by <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow key and make possible changes. Save it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and `y`.
- Now update grub by:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Restart your system, you problem should be solved:

  ```
  reboot
  ```

Reply if something goes wrong..